Converting a json file into a csv file with more columns - Python
I would like to convert a json file below:
    [
        {
            "userid": "5275800381",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Ah",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
        {
            "userid": "5824657725",
            "status": "UserStatus.LAST_MONTH",
            "name": "A45",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
        {
            "userid": "5160075986",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "CTLA",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "james888"
        }
    ]

into a csv file with more columns and without duplicates as follows:
    username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id,is_bot,is_admin,dc_id,have_photo,phone,elaborated

The output file should be:
    username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id,is_bot,is_admin,dc_id,have_photo,phone,elaborated
    ,5275800381,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
    ,5824657725,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
    james888,5160075986,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False

I have tried the following codes:
    import json

    with open('target_user2.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        target = json.load(fp) #this file contains the json

    with open('members2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:    # target_userid2.txt or target_userid2.json
        nf.write('username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id,is_bot,is_admin,dc_id,have_photo,phone,elaborated' + '\n')
        for item in target:
            if item['userid'] in [x['userid'] for x in target]:
                if item['username'] == "None":
                    item['username'] == ""
                    record = item['username'] + ',' + item['userid'] + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False'
                    nf.write(json.dumps(record).replace('"', '') + '\n')       # write data without ""

it does not work because error is generated by item['user id'] (user id with a space not working), but item['userid'] works.
How can I fix this?
Based on advice from Barmar, it WORKs which I update my codes below:
    import json

    with open('target_user2.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        target = json.load(fp) #this file contains the json

    with open('members2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:    # target_userid2.txt or target_userid2.json
        nf.write('username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id,is_bot,is_admin,dc_id,have_photo,phone,elaborated' + '\n')
        for item in target:
            if item['userid'] in [x['userid'] for x in target]:
                if item['username'] == "None":
                    item['username'] == ""
                record = item['username'] + ',' + item['userid'] + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False'
                nf.write(json.dumps(record).replace('"', '') + '\n')       # write data without ""

                

However, there is another issue coming up which is not intended. When username is None in target_user2.json, I assigned it to blank:
    item['username'] == ""           
        

It does not work; it writes all usernames with the same values from target_user2.json.
What is wrong with that?

Use the csv module to create a CSV file.

item indexes should be the keys from the JSON file, not the column headings in the CSV.

if item['userid'] in [x['userid'] for x in target] will always be true, since it will match itself.

To prevent duplicates, create a set of userids. Before writing to the CSV file, check if the userid is in the set. Then add the userid to the set so you won't write it again.

item['username'] == "" is a comparison. Use = for assignment. But why are you setting it to an empty string when it's not None?

Does this answer your question? How can I convert JSON to CSV?

Check out csv.dictReader() and csv.dictWriter()

Use the csv module to correctly handle CSV formatting, such as fields that contain quotes or the delimiter(comma in this case).  csv.DictWriter also helps with managing the columns and default False value for missing fields:
import csv
import json

with open('input.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# newline='' is an open requirement for writing csv files per documentation.
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as f:
    columns = 'username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id,is_bot,is_admin,dc_id,have_photo,phone,elaborated'.split(',')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=columns, restval=False)  # restval is the default value of fields
    writer.writeheader()
    ids = set()  # Track unique IDs
    for user in data:
        user_id = user['userid']
        if user_id not in ids:
            # Build a dict with fields to change.
            row = {'username': user['username'] if user['username'] != 'None' else '',
                   'user id': user_id,
                   #'name': user['name'],  # Always False in example, but if you want it...
                   'is_bot': user['bot']}
            writer.writerow(row)
            ids.add(user_id)

Output:
username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id,is_bot,is_admin,dc_id,have_photo,phone,elaborated
,5275800381,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
,5824657725,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
james888,5160075986,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False


yep, it is much better than mine

It works faster than my codes, but I am more comfortable with my solution because it is simpler and I can retrieve only Valid usernames, or Invalid usernames with a small piece of codes

@JamesBlack You should still get comfortable using the csv module instead of manually joining strings with commas.  If the data has columns with quote or delimiter characters or newlines it will break.  csv will make sure the data is properly escaped and quoted to generate a valid CSV.

@JamesBlack, another way to think about it... you're duplicating work that's already been done and tested by many people over the years (decades); "rolling your own" is guaranteed to introduce small, silly errors (and like Mark suggested not-so small and silly errors). And it's not just you, anyone here (definitely me!) would be susceptible to making those kinds of mistakes. A new library might feel awkward, but think of the energy you might spend fixing your own mistakes and put that energy toward learning something new, and dependable.


Use the csv module to write CSV files, rather than formatting it yourself.

Use a set to detect duplicate userids and skip them.

Fix the logic when replacing None username with an empty string.

When accessing the JSON, you have to use userid as the key, not user id.


import csv

userids = set()

with open('members2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:    # target_userid2.txt or target_userid2.json
    nf_csv = csv.writer(nf)
    nf_csv.writerow(['username', 'user id', 'access hash', 'name', 'group', 'group id', 'is_bot', 'is_admin', 'dc_id', 'have_photo', 'phone', 'elaborated'])
    for item in target:
        if item['userid'] not in userids: # prevent duplicate userids
            userids.add(item['userid'])
            if item['username'] == "None":
                item['username'] = ""
            record = [item['username'], item['userid'], 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False']
            nf_csv.writerow(record)


Tried your codes above, but there is error: AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'

Sorry, that should be writerow

still generates the same error

Did you change it in both places?

Great help from Bamar, I corrected everything he advised; and it works very well:
    import json

    with open('target_user2.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        target = json.load(fp) #this file contains the json

    with open('members2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:    # target_userid2.txt or target_userid2.json
        nf.write('username,user id,access hash,name,group,group id,is_bot,is_admin,dc_id,have_photo,phone,elaborated' + '\n')
        for item in target:
            if item['userid'] in [x['userid'] for x in target]:     # remove space between user and id to avoid error
                if item['username'] == "None":
                    item['username'] = ""
                record = item['username'] + ',' + item['userid'] + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False' + ',' + 'False'
                nf.write(json.dumps(record).replace('"', '') + '\n')       # write data without ""


Why are you calling json.dumps()? That's not needed.
